# Rxjava merge multiple obsevables without interleaving their flow

Tags: rx-java, fifo

[data fetching flow (updated)- each flow use its own thread (Scheduler.io)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ovIH.png)

I am beginner of Rxjava, i can not figure out how to express the red and yellow arrows in Rxjava way.

The difficulties for me are:

1. Collect all observable's data but no interleaving. the number of
2. observable is variable, not fixed number in red arrow.

I have read books and search but more and more headache, i don't know which way i should go. For the red arrow part,i could simply use a blocking queue as usual, but it may be better to have the whole chain written in Rxjava way.

Comment: Why you say no concat? that's exactly what you need

Comment: It is because concat is in fixed order, always specified by parameter order. But in my case, i should pick up the first arrive which may not be the first in parameters.

Comment: so you really want a merge that delay other observable events until the current one is complete? maybe if you describe what you are really trying to do it gets easier to help

Comment: @Daniele Segato 
Each data flow in attached picture is executing in parallel, i would call subscribOn(Scheduler.io()) to allocate a thread to it.

Comment: I still don't think you are explaining what you need.

Comment: @Daniele Segato 
My current implementation is thread pool + blocking queue, each data flow use one thread and they will put its result ( a list containing all matched rows) into a blocking queue.  So the order among results are not important. Could you show me an equivalent of that in Rxjava way ?

Comment: So, let me get this straight: you have N parallel task to run and you want to run them in some kind of background thread pool and get results by those task as they come, you do not care about the order. This is really different from a FIFO queue.

Comment: Yes, that is exact what i want, may be i use wrong term FIFO,i use FIFO to describe how the output writer deal with the results and  emphasize 'no concat','no merge'.

Comment: the funny thing is merge is exactly what you need and I really don't get why you say "I don't want to use it". Can't really answer your question unless you get it straight and "fix-it" as in "you actually write the question with what you need and not what you think you need"

Comment: Sorry, make you confused.  When i try to use Rxjava to replace current implementation, i also change the result of thread (now observable) from list<row> to row. So  'merge' will interleave rows from different observable.

Comment: I gave you an answer but I still think your question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can understand the question yet.

Assuming this is the question:

- you start from tasks producing list of data `List<DATA>`, let's call it batch of data;
- all these tasks are executed in parallel in a thread pool;
- you receive those batches and process them
- you do not care about the order of the batches but you DO care of the inner order of the elements in those batches
- you are trying to migrate this to RxJava

As far as I can tell from your question you already started and your task are now producing `Observable<Data>` in place of `List<DATA>`.

This is the first thing I would change: since you care about the internal order of the batches I would keep the list and thus makes your task return `Observable<List<DATA>>`.

So you'll end up with a bunch of `Observable<List<DATA>>`, one for each parallel task:

```
List<Observable<List<DATA>>> tasks = ...;
List<Observable<List<DATA>>> parallelTask = new Arraylist(tasks.size());
for (Observable<List<DATA>> task : tasks) {
    // execute all the task in a separate thread
    // change Schedulers to your own pool schedulers if you want
    parallelTask.add(task.scheduleOn(Schedulers.io()));
}
Observable.merge(parallelTasks)
    .concatMap(batch -> Observable.from(batch)) // read below
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // or whichever thread you want to process the data
    .subscribe(data -> {
        // process data as it comes
    }, throwable -> {
        // handle error
    });
```

This is what it does

1. first merge all the batches observables into a single observable
2. then specify the thread in which the subscription should happen
3. then `concatMap` convert the batch (`List<DATA>`) into a stream of events of type `DATA` preserving their order (you'll not get data from different batches until this one is over)
4. then specify the thread in which you want to observe your data and process them
5. finally it subscribe to the data to process them

Comment: `List<Observable<List<DATA>>> parallelTasks = ...;
Observable.merge(parallelTasks)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // use your own schedulers with a Thread Pool if you prefer
    .concatMap(batch -> Observable.from(batch)) // read below
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // or whichever thread you want to process the data
    .subscribe(data -> {
        // process data as it comes
    }, throwable -> {
        // handle error
    });`

Comment: Sorry, i press enter to input above comments by mistake.

1 In your solution, are all parallelTasks  executing in different thread of Scheduler.IO pool ? If not, how can i do that ?

2 If i add timerout(10,Seconds) before subscirbe(), i will get TimerOutExecption, can i stop those parallelTasks by just calling unsubscribe() ?

Comment: 1. that depends on how you build those observable. 2. I changed the answer to make sure all of those run in parallel 3. when there are no more subscribers an observable usually unsubscribe unless it is a connectable observable. A failure should trigger an unsubscribe to all underlying Observable. But unsubscribing them does not mean they stop executing, that depends on how they are build.